# Is there a user constructed version of the pain field?

Tags: planetside-2

I have noticed that I lose shield and health when I walk next to a hive base built by the enemy what is the component that causes this effect ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is the [Skywall Shield Emitter](http://planetside.wikia.com/wiki/Construction_System#Skywall_Shield_Emitter). It looks like this:

[image: Skywall Shield Emitter]

The color depends on the faction which built it. This is a Vanu one, so it's purple.

When an enemy soldier comes into contact with them, they will set them on fire and do damage over time. That DOT will persist for a while even after they leave the area. If they leave immediately they might survive with HP in the red zone.

They form a mushroom-shaped cupola 15m over the generator. The intended purpose is to prevent light assaults from flying in and to counter galaxy drops, so the enemy is forced to attack on a ground route. However, some players will try to place them in ditches (like here) so even ground-based attackers have no other choice than walking through them.

Comment: Is that abuse of the mechanic known to the developers? Is it even considered an abuse or is it seen as "smart/tactical placement" ?

Comment: @Eternal_Light In this particular case I believe that the builder also exploited a bug, because it seemed like the structures were somehow placed below ground. But whether or not this is fair-play is a different question.